# smoothing the placement of vertex

Tags: shaders, topology

I'm trying to model a car, when joining two hood and the fender I had to tweak to geometry to make everything quads but I ended up with sort of bump as you can see:

[image]

Here is my topology:

[image]

each time I try to move a vertex to remove the bump I create another,

Is there a way or an add on to get perfect curvature?

Here is the file:
[image]

Comment: could you please share this part of your mesh?

Comment: Yes how should I export it (which format) ?

Comment: Please use this link and upload the blend file directly https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: I have edited the question, now you can download the mesh

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use a simpler topology. I've done this from scratch, using your object underneath, first I've used the *Snap* option then the *Shrinkwrap* modifier so that it sticks to your object. Maybe you should use the same method, but starting with a duplication of your own mesh so that you have the right amount of edges...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In blender 2.8 you can try to fix it with the smooth laplacian in the special option (w -> smooth laplacian).
It tend to keep the general shape while smoothing "wiggly" surfaces.

For more info see the official blender documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/laplacian_smooth.html